# Sitecore - Store Images in Core database

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, sitecore

Is it possible to access Images from the MediaLibrary stored in the Core database.

I get the item URL from the Core database using following code:
      Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem)

But when I try to set image src value with that URL it says: Resource not found.

Comment: What images are you storing/accessing in the Core database? Why are they there and not in master/web?

Comment: User Profile Images. We cannot store that in the Web or Master.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should store your images in the Master database. This will correctly allow the media to be published/unpublished which is not possible for items stored in core database.

If you STILL require the images to be served from core db then you could append `sc_content=core` to the image URL, e.g.

`<img src="/-/media/Experience-Profile/Defaults/Channel.png?sc_content=core" />`

This will force this particular request from the media library in core database.